# Can I calculate how effective my close votes are?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, statistics, data-explorer

From my point of view, with the giant close votes queue leaving so many close votes attempts to a state of "*aged away*", I'd like to know if my close votes actions are meaningful or meaningless.

Consider Stack Overflow users with **at least one successful closing vote** round (i.e.: being among the listed close voters of a question, regardless if it was reopened or not later). Those users have a ratio of close success of:

```
successful_close_attempts / total_close_votes
```

I'd also like to compare my close vote efficacy to other users.  Are there stats on the average and the median values for those success rates?

Is that part of the data that you can discover at [25,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) or is that queryable via [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

---

<sub>I only know that I have casted 1,356 close votes on SO.</sub>

Comment: That is pretty meaningless, success rate is completely dominated by the tags you visit.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, I didn't thought about that. But it means that you already studied those stats and that you already noticed that some users have very different rates than others, correlatively to their watched tags?

Comment: No, I don't look at other users' stats.  I think turning this into some kind of competition is quite unhealthy.

Comment: @HansPassant I feel my votes end up _wasted 80% of the time_: it's **not** for competition at all, it's to get an idea if I'm doing a bad job or not, if the multiple minutes I spend on each review to read it, understand it and measure if the problem is reproducible or not are worth it.

Comment: You do have enough rep to get a birds-eye view.   Visit the [votes] tab in your profile, navigate at least a month back.  Anything actually closed has the [closed] annotation, deleted and roomba-ed posts are purple.  You can't separate by tag, so you still don't know that much.

Comment: Here is a [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/873421?UserId=1033581) that shows how much posts you managed to close and where you are relative to others (not to be used to turn this into a competition). You can compare that number with what you found on your votes tab as indicated by Hans.

Comment: Just for comparison: I casted 66,837 close votes in total with 14756 posts closed, based on the SEDE query.

Comment: I have cast 8500 close votes (nice round number, I know) and have closed 1755 posts. Roughly a 20% success rate (1755 / 85) on close votes in comparison to rene's 22% success rate (14756 / 668.37), and your 11% success rate (150 / 13.56).

Comment: @rene of course, sure, it's not a competition, at all,  but ranked at a mere 236th I find your script unwelcoming... maybe it's buggy.... :)

Comment: @MartinJames I never figured I would have closed more posts than you, I'm #216 on the list.

Comment: Based on nothing I would say a "success" rate of around 20% sounds OK as the pool of questions that get a close vote is high and you only have 1 vote of the required 5 votes. Only users that primarily wield their goldbadge dupe hammer could have significant higher rates.

Comment: @rene The main difference is whether your someone going around finding bad questions and flagging them, or using review queues (or similar mechanisms, like CV chat) to find questions already acted on by lots of other people (hence why they're in the queue) and acting on those.  The latter will have a higher close rate than the former, because they'll consistently be casting votes on posts that already have more close votes, and that are more likely to be shown to more people.

Comment: Ranking high in that list is pretty iffy.  Getting so many questions closed but not deleted is nothing much to brag about.

Comment: @Servy while reviewers have that advantage, I imagine users that follow their favorite tag could be as effective, assuming the tag is healthy and those with close vote privilege have a common understanding about what they want to close.

Comment: @HansPassant just so I understand correctly: are you suggesting that after close voting posts should be revisited in say 6 to 8 weeks to be delete voted?

Comment: @TinyGiant well, I've been distracted recently by fighting against the hordes of evil blogge beasts that invaded from the dark realms of Mediacrity.

Comment: @rene - by far the most deleted posts that I actively participated moderating in were deleted by the roomba.  That's why I recommended going back a month, roomba isn't very fast.  I personally very rarely vote to delete, two days is far too long.

Comment: @rene Both types of users are entirely healthy.  My point was that two different people, engaging in very different *but equally appropriate* behaviors, will tend to have very different stats in this regard.  My point was that this makes it a not very useful state for precisely that reason, the value is not indicative of whether you're doing this appropriately or not.

Comment: @Servy I don't think we disagree. The only difference is that I think on average all our stats will be the same (so around 20%)  while you think they will wildly differ. Knowing that value doesn't tell you a thing, so we leave it at that.

Comment: @rene I think Servy's point about using review queues/CV chat matters a lot here. For example I almost exclusively vote on questions in the close queue or socvr. I have about the same as Cœur's cvs (1600), but more than an 80% close success rate. This just shows the power of more "organized" close votes.

Comment: @River hmm, that is indeed much different. Thanks for sharing that

Comment: I can't see this being on topic, and because you're deleting dissenting viewpoints about your utility on the site, this discussion seems to be selecting for a pat-on-the-back. I have VTCed appropriately. This question isn't about MSO, or SO. It's about you which is too localized; and, at that, we can't be honest.

Comment: Yes. Yes, you are.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Perhaps you are unaware that only moderators can "delete dissenting viewpoints". I cannot see them but perhaps they were phrased in a rude way?

Comment: I find this an interesting question - I've occasionally wondered, myself, how effective my close votes are... To the topic of whether it makes a difference whether one closes in a tag or a queue I can definitely say that most of what I vote to close in my main tags (ms-word, word-vba) do NOT go on hold or get deleted. And that can be very frustrating. But many that I vote on in the queue do at least go on hold.

Comment: @EvanCarroll see my edit.  I think this is a generally applicable question and not too localized for a single user.  Whether the statistics are actually meaningful is another story entirely.

Comment: The important takeaway is that the number is meaningless because there are so many factors that come into play other than whether or not you are voting to close questions correctly. You may have incorrectly voted to close a now closed question which would boost your score, and you may have correctly voted to close a question that did not end up closed for any number of reasons which would lower your score.

Comment: @TinyGiant: me, I have a 3rd category: questions that should have rightfully been closed but were not, because too few diligent close-voters actually saw it. (Or because they did but were out of close-votes for the day. I have that as well.)

Comment: Note that if you don't have the reputation to view deleted questions and you calculate your close % from this query the results will probably skew your results higher as you'll see a lower count for your votes cast. I've apparently cast 563 CVs (according to my account) of which 388 resulted in closures, putting me at a 69% closure rate. Although I've done over 1000 CV reviews in the queue which are almost exclusively closes (and most closed have now been deleted, as indicated by no link in my review history). This is likely why @River's is much higher as well.

Comment: @usr2564301 would that not qualify as _"you may have correctly voted to close a question that did not end up closed for any number of reasons"_

Comment: @TinyGiant: I mean the *vast* difference between "I am apparently the only one who thinks it's a simple typo – *shrug*" and clear off-topic questions which have *every* reason to get closed (and probably deleted as well). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50952877/2564301), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50919240/2564301), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51079258/2564301), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51168716/2564301) …

Comment: @pnuts I'm sorry that the facts my query reveals make you feel you have wasted you time. I value your contributions no matter how much or how little posts you close.

Comment: @rene Does that query take into account deleted posts too? I'm thinking it doesn't, which will heavily bias the results. Eg, just browsing my votes tab pages, I'm seeing that around ~half of the posts I've recently VTC'd on are now closed, which is quite far from my percentage of 15%.

Comment: @CertainPerformance no, the info on deleted posts is removed from most of the tables.

Answer (score 14):

We considered a personal 'review efficacy' page for each user. It seemed appealing to have something that encouraged people to spend more time in queues that were most intuitive for them by showing them how effective they were being.

As we started considering possible designs and implementations, we realized how much of a *bad* idea it was turning out to be. You're essentially saying:

- You're really great at this
- You really stink at this
- You're not really any different than anyone else at this

for *motivational* purposes, only the first one was really shiny, the other two were more brutally honest in most cases than anything else.

But, depending on the tags you visit (as others mentioned), being *really* great was rather subjective; and we just wouldn't have a whole lot to show folks that weren't at least somewhat active in the tags that would get you a Generalist badge at some point in the site's evolution.

You have to go with a median from the tag group, and then a number representing the efficacy of each reviewer. So, being wrong 6/10 times in Cobol would look a lot different than being *right* 3/10 times in PHP, compared to respective medians. So if your goals are:

- We want graphs where people can realistically work to make them go up and to the right pretty consistently, and,
- We *only occasionally* want the lack of progress to be a bit discouraging to people that just *chronically* get it wrong

... it just became crazy to fathom the individual math cases, much less maintain them, and then design around that.

I still think there's opportunity to discretely tell folks *hey, you're really good at this particular thing, we'd love it if you did more*, and even the subtle reverse of that, but when we looked at it with numbers and graphs in our hands, they turned out to be the wrong tools.

Always open to suggestions, I'd *love* more enticement into (and potentially out of!) the queues, but it's a tricky problem and *really* easy to inadvertently hurt people's feelings if you don't nail it just right.

Comment: "being wrong 6/10 times in Cobol would look a lot different than being right 3/10 times", no I'm not wrong. Remember, close votes do expire. So that if 6/10 or 3/10 of my votes resulted in the question being closed means exactly that: there where 4 other timely close votes that resulted in the question being closed.