# Efficiency of review queues - too many "aged away" flags

Tags: discussion, flags

There are similar questions asked too, however those are old and now the situation might be even worse.

- [Why were my older close flags "aged away"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away)
- [How many aged away flags are common?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335820/how-many-aged-away-flags-are-common)
- [Are there too few moderators? I have over 50% "aged away" flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339851/are-there-too-few-moderators-i-have-over-50-aged-away-flags)

Currently 55% of my post flags are aged away:

[image]

I understand there are huge numbers of flags and less volunteers to clean up queues (most of my flags would have been close votes in case I'd have enough rep to cast them), however it's still frustrating to see the majority of my flags are just useless.

Reading comments on linked questions I feel others have the same opinion too.

Unfortunately I don't have any good suggestion, however I'm unhappy with this situation, feeling like my contribution to the site is ignored.

### Update *(for those who think my post doesn't contain an actual question)*

Although my post doesn't contain any question marks, I hoped it's clear enough now I try to further clarify it:

we have a problem: there are too many low quality questions not closed on Stack Overflow

- this is frustrating for me, as a user without enough rep to cast close votes, as I feel my flags are ignored
- it's also bad for users with higher reps volunteering to review the queue getting unmanageable number of votes
- and also bad for the users asking those questions as they also feel they're ignored and no reaction on their question. While having a question closed isn't definitely positive, it helps to find the direction how to improve / where to ask it.

So I've posted this question to highlight the issue (again) and initiate some discussions, maybe we can find some solutions which could help this situation.

Comment: The size of the close vote queue has been a problem for a few years now. There has been a few good suggestions, and some less good changes. I think the [so] staff considers things mostly acceptable as it stands.

Comment: There is a dedicated chat room [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) that helps to get recent active questions closed by means of [tag:cv-pls] requests. Before joining do study their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq). I'm sorry that it is a bit lengthy but it reads as a thriller ...

Comment: Thanks @rene! However I'm not sure it's a final solution. Seems to be having a second line of close vote queue, as the official one doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Aged away flags suck a bit, and closable questions remaining open is not ideal; but a lot of grief comes from closed questions. Making it easier would make the amount of grief to increase. The solution is not that, but to help users make better questions in the first place (and there are some efforts going into that direction already).

Comment: It only takes a minor attitude adjustment. Stop calling it a "contribution" and start assuming that it is burden. Along the lines of "I saw a lousy post, now I need 3 other users to look at it as well". That is no fun for anybody, small wonder there are not enough volunteers for that awful job. You've been a member for over 3 years but downvoted only 35 times. You can easily get that number up.

Comment: Good one @HansPassant, I usually DV when I flag to close something, hoping for Roomba to get off its feet.

Comment: Also in my experience it vastly depends on what type of flags you cast. Off-topic flags are in my observations far more likely to age away then other types of flags, but this could just be me.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I thought that maybe you were going to suggest that the flags should not be aged away so quickly?

Comment: @rene I mostly see that as a place to target individual questions rather than making much of a difference to the overall size of the review queue. But the only real reason to target a question would be to get it closed where it wouldn't otherwise have, in which case too few people would've seen it to be worth taking the time to do something about it (as opposed to just spending some time handling questions in the review queue, that is). Although I guess if you just want your flags to be processed, or if you don't like the review queue for some reason...

Comment: @Dukeling yes, that is a fair point. The room also offers a few userscripts which allow reviewers to use their votes effectively. But that only becomes handy after 3K of rep, so that is of no use for this OP.

Comment: It's an old problem, with the problem getting worse. I think you'll find many users with a disturbing percentage of [aged away flags](https://i.imgur.com/ryQp9Be.jpg)

Comment: Just thinking about it now - the close vote review queue (and others?) requires way too many clicks. I wouldn't be surprised if that contributes heavily to the queue size problem. The goal should be 1 click, or maybe 2, for the most common actions, not 3-5.

Comment: @Dukeling I am not sure if this is really a problem. To me it typically takes 3-5 minutes to complete 40 reviews, meaning even if we would assume unlikely case of most of my time in it spent on clicking (even though it isn't) then it would still be minor. [Lack of reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252600/839601) seems to be more plausible explanation of the problems with close worthy questions hanging open

Comment: @AndrewMorton: no, I don't really have any suggestion, just shared my frustration. I know there were a lot of discussion about that and I don't feel experienced enough for judging them.

Comment: @gnat There can be many reasons why people don't do more reviews, which may include the overall experience being less than optimal. You must be a robot, because I probably spend 5-10 seconds per review (so 3-6 minutes for 40) to **just** go through the close dialog (after making a decision), and I know the close dialog like the back of my hand. Some questions require a lot more time to review than that, but there are also plenty of questions that can be judged in less time (especially with certain tag/reason combinations). We're actively encouraging people to *not* close questions in review.

Comment: @Dukeling wrt the too many clicks: see the [close vote review schortcuts](https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts) script. It adds keyboard control, no clicking needed ...

Comment: consider [edit]ing your question to turn it into request for [meta-tag:statistics]. Data to look for is about as follows: 1) pick users active in casting close flags - eg those having 100 or more flags 2) of these, pick flaggers who seem to do it right - that is, having solid ratio of declines to helpful, like 1:20 or 1:30 etc 3) for flaggers picked at last step, find out average percent of expired flags. That looks like a sensible estimation of review efficiency

Comment: For comparison, 80 % of my close votes age away. See [Can I calculate how effective my close votes are?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370951/can-i-calculate-how-effective-my-close-votes-are).

Comment: @gnat: I'm not really interested in statistics, I'm interested in making the site better. Please see my update on the question.

Comment: I've been thinking like you in the past, I just asked to do things that seemed like "obvious" improvements to me. This has changed after I learned to make statistics requests as sort of prelude to requesting something. I still want (and ask for) improvements but preparatory stats requests make everything so much smoother: first these help myself better understand what exactly to ask for (in your case, it would be like "efficient handling of close flags cast by proven trusted flaggers") and second, stats make it easier to argue that we need improvements ("too many worthy flags are wasted")...

Comment: ...granted, sometimes there is kind of opposite result, I dropped few suggestions when requested stats demonstrated that what I planned to ask for won't make substantial impact. But frankly this doesn't feel troublesome, okay I learned that particular idea isn't worth pushing for, so be it, I can try something different

Comment: thanks @gnat! that make much more sense now

Comment: I am a bit surprised by the comments here;  I looked at my statistics, and I have exactly one aged away flag out of 190.  I guess maybe I'm picky enough about what I flag that they end up being very accurate?

Comment: @Claies Maybe you flag much more popular questions which are anyway seen by more people. I'm mainly interested in VBA which is not the mainstream of this site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a few thoughts on this. But first, let's get a broad picture of how many close flags *actually* age away. I've collected all close flags and close votes on Stack Overflow over the past 24 months, separated them by close reason, and charted the percentage raised in each month that aged away:

> [image: chart of close flags cast each month that later aged away, separated by close reason]
>   **close flags**

> [image: chart of close flags cast each month that later aged away, separated by close reason]
>   **close votes**

As shown, under a quarter of all duplicate *votes* age away: gold badge closing is extremely effective. However, duplicate *flags* are not nearly so effective, with close to 40% of them aging away regularly. The least-aged flag - and also second-least-aged vote - is for "primarily opinion-based". "Unclear" is heavily aged for both flags and votes, pushing 50% in both cases.

Given the disproportionate ability of folks to close duplicates, it would probably help a lot here to find a way of encouraging more folks to review duplicate *flags*. However, no such option is available for the rest.

I think it's important to remember here that aging isn't a terrible thing in and of itself: before we aged close flags, they could hang there in limbo for *years*, long after any problems had already been dealt with and everyone involved had moved on. [Aging offers a resolution of sorts, and a chance to approach the problem from an alternate angle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away/287211#287211).

But more than anything else... I think it's important to be judicious with your flags. Closing is... Not actually a very good way of dealing with poor-quality questions. It's very effective at dealing with [attractive nuisances](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367893/the-most-heartbreaking-question-the-eager-but-hopeless/367895#367895), but an awful lot of questions aren't... very attractive, and downvoting is a far more effective means of getting them *out of the way*.

Traditionally, two of the biggest "attractive nuisance" problems were... Subjective questions and duplicates: both tend to attract answers that aren't really needed, depriving other questions of the attention that they do need. I don't think it's coincidental that these are also the areas where close *voters* see their votes having the biggest effect; as a flagger, I'd recommend focusing your efforts on those two problems as well.

Comment: While you're at it, can you extend the query to the last 36 months, instead of 24? (I'm a bit interested in June-July 2016) Thanks!

Comment: As a C++-Mjolnir having an eye on all "Possible duplicate" comments in the tag while I'm around, I find it unsurprising that dupe votes age away less often than dupe flags. The votes, on average, are of *much* higher quality than the flags. Finding and choosing good dupe targets is not at all trivial, especially when you are relatively new.

Comment: Votes and flags combined, 36 months @BhargavRao: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi0iW.png

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't surprise me much @BaummitAugen. Nothing like answering a bunch of questions to get a feel for what's already been answered.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score -18):

Without inferring being better, for efficiency only, users without the close vote privilege should not flag. Starting with zero votes distracts votes from questions that start with one close vote.

Once you get a vote, a first vote could be balanced with perhaps ten or more votes on questions in the queue. When that becomes onerous you would stop first voting.

Basically the more you first vote relative to queue vote the less efficient closing becomes. For queue efficiency, being a non-first voter would be preferable.

Comment: That has some logic, however I don't see what we should do instead with low quality questions? Writing a comment often doesn't help (if a question off-topic, than is should be closed, not begging OP to close it theirself). Flagging for mods? that's even worst. Just ignore and accept we're "young" on the site and can't mark crappy content?

Comment: you can still cast up/down votes. @MátéJuhász

Comment: @KevinB those won't help cleaning up the site.

Comment: Sure they do. Negatively scored posts get automagically deleted.

Comment: @KevinB (a) not when they have answers; (b) some flags-to-close are for duplicates.

Comment: (a) yes, if the answers are downvoted too. (b) duplicates are poorly researched.

Comment: @KevinB The only [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) task which deletes questions with answers `RemoveAbandonedClosed` (ignoring migrations) requires the question to be closed and both the question and all answers to have scores <= 0 (and other requirements). A blanket statement that "duplicates are poorly researched" is, at best, misleading. While *some* are certainly poorly researched, it's quite inaccurate to say that as a blanket statement.